Filter by criteria and avoid creating duplicates
I want to filter data by year and month criteria from selected sheet.
When I select the sheet name and the year then click the filter button to filter data from a selected sheet it gives me

error code 1004

on
erng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=crng, copytorange:=ws.Range("E" & lastrow & ":S" & lastrow)

It highlights as attached.
error code
Sub myFilter()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim crng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ews As Worksheet
Dim erng As Range
Dim i As Integer 'Declare i as an integer for the loop
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Monthly Summary") 'Use Set to assign ws as a worksheet

Set crng = ws.Range("B4").CurrentRegion
ws.Range("E5", ws.Range("E5").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear

For i = 3 To wb.Worksheets.Count
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Specify ws.Rows.Count to refer to the worksheet rows
    Set ews = wb.Worksheets(i)
    Set erng = ews.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    erng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=crng, copytorange:=ws.Range("E" & lastrow & ":S" & lastrow)
    ws.Range("E" & lastrow & ":S" & lastrow).Delete shift:=xlUp
Next i

End Sub

A second issue is after saving data, when I search by year and month then edit the data and forget to click the update button and click the save button again it will save as new. I want to prevent duplicate by year and month.
link for the file

We only need to target the top left cell for copying:

ws.Range("E" & lastrow & ":S" & lastrow)
Change to
ws.Range("E" & lastrow)

But the issue was ws.Range("B4").CurrentRegion was including the entire UsedRange.  CurrentRegion range extends across all contiguous (connected) cells.

Set erng = Intersect(ews.UsedRange.Offset(2), ews.UsedRange)

Sub myFilter()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim crng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ews As Worksheet
    Dim erng As Range
    Dim i As Integer 'Declare i as an integer for the loop
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Monthly Summary") 'Use Set to assign ws as a worksheet

    Set crng = ws.Range("B4").CurrentRegion
    ws.Range("E5", ws.Range("E5").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 3 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Specify ws.Rows.Count to refer to the worksheet rows
        Set ews = wb.Worksheets(i)
        Set erng = Intersect(ews.UsedRange.Offset(2), ews.UsedRange)
        erng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=crng, copytorange:=ws.Range("E" & lastrow)
        ws.Range("E" & lastrow & ":S" & lastrow).Delete shift:=xlUp
    Next i
End Sub


Thank you for the respond. The edited code works but it brings all data from all the sheets. What I aim is to activate the activesheet, and the criteria year then when click filter buttton to filter through the year column to filter based on the selected year only. Thank you

@Vickwa Good to hear.
